# What is the difference between LSTMBlockCell and BasicLSTMCell in Tensorflow contrib.rnn

Tags: tensorflow

I know that LSTMBlockCell is efficient to initialize at the begining of training. The official API guides of Tensorflow said that LSTMBlockCell add a forgot_bias. Can I just replace the BasicLSTMCell with LSTMBlockCell in my RNN models? And there are too many stuffs in tf.contrib.rnn, I feel that those APIs are really inconsistent.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between `LSTMBlockCell` and `BasicLSTMCell` is that `BasicLSTMCell` is implemented in terms of primitive TensorFlow ops, so it's useful code to copy and edit if you want to play with your LSTM architecture. `LSTMBlockCell`, on the other hand, uses a fused kernel which allows for much better performance.

Comment: I trained a model used both LSTMBlockCell and BasicLSTMCell , but BasicLSTMCell works much better with a higher test accuracy